# How can I adjust my position to a specific point after rotating?

Tags: unity

I have a player that moves on the platform and rotates 90 degree when it collides with a bend. After it stop rotating it must continue moving from the middle of the next platform. I could set its position manually but I don't want it to teleport. I have tried to reach the middle by changing player's rotating speed. I want to know if there is a proper way to do this ? Thank you

[Here I reduced rotation speed and it's center point seems at the same point with platform's middle](https://files.fm/f/3gy9h6jz7)

[Here I increased rotation speed a little bit and player goes out of platform's middle](https://files.fm/f/w9bdcswtn)

**Movement controller:**

```
public class PlayerMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ScriptablePlayerMovementSettings _movementSettings;

    private float _direction = 0;
    public float Direction { get => _direction; set => _direction = value; }

    private Vector3 _lastRotation = Vector3.zero;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Direction != 0)
        {
            Rotate();
        }
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        Vector3 movement = transform.forward * _movementSettings.MovementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    private void Rotate()
    {
        Vector3 targetRotation = GetLastRotation() + Vector3.up * Direction * 90f;
        targetRotation = new Vector3(targetRotation.x, targetRotation.y % 360, targetRotation.z);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation), _movementSettings.RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.eulerAngles.Equals(Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation).eulerAngles))
        {
            SetLastRotation();
            Direction = 0;
        }
    }

    private void SetLastRotation()
    {
        _lastRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    }

    private Vector3 GetLastRotation()
    {
        return _lastRotation;
    }

}
```

**I get the direction value based on bend type:**

```
public class PlatformCollisionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<PlayerMovementController>() != null)
        {
            PlayerMovementController playerMovementController = other.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<PlayerMovementController>();
            playerMovementController.Direction = (GetComponentInParent<MiddlePlatformMono>().GetPlatformType == PlatformType.TurnLeft) ? -1f : 1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for moving the player? That will help us propose solutions that work within what you have.

Comment: Of course, i've added my codes.

Comment: Just use some kind of damped response, instead of teleportation. let k=0.9 in CurrentPosition = k*CurrentPosition + (1-k)*DesitredPosition; The player will never reach the Desired position but will slowly move towards it. K is an adjustable weighted response.